# cpp to delphi "byte [enum]"

Tags: c++, delphi, enums

I have a problem with struct translation from C++ to Delphi.

In a C++ header, three fields of a struct have a byte array to a enum value.
I'm supposing its the order value since the enum has no values.

```
//Part of struct declaring a byte array of NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX

    BYTE                byColorSimilar[NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX];// Object color similarity, the range :0-100, represents an array subscript Colors, see EM_COLOR_TYPE, 
    BYTE                byUpperBodyColorSimilar[NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX]; // When upper body color similarity (valid object type man , 
    BYTE                byLowerBodyColorSimilar[NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX]; // Lower body color similarity when objects (object type human valid ,
```

The enum has the `NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX`

```
// color type
typedef enum
{
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_RED,                                     // red
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_YELLOW,                                  // yellow
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_GREEN,                                   // green
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_CYAN,                                    // cyan
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_BLUE,                                    // glue
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_PURPLE,                                  // purple
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_BLACK,                                   // black
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_WHITE,                                   // white
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX,
}EM_COLOR_TYPE;
```

I have tried using `XXX : array[0..99] of byte` since the comments on the first declaration say: **the range :0-100**, but the pointer result is misplaced data.

How to declare this var in Delphi? Using enum order as a value? Like: NET_COLOR_TYPE_RED as 0, and NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX as 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the  `NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX` enum value to declare the arrays, just as the C++ code does. Remember that the upper bound of a 0-indexed array is -1 of the element count, eg:

```pascal
type
  EM_COLOR_TYPE = (
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_RED,                                     // red
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_YELLOW,                                  // yellow
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_GREEN,                                   // green
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_CYAN,                                    // cyan
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_BLUE,                                    // glue
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_PURPLE,                                  // purple
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_BLACK,                                   // black
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_WHITE,                                   // white
    NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX
 );

byColorSimilar: array[0..NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX-1] of Byte;
byUpperBodyColorSimilar: array[0..NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX-1] of Byte;
byLowerBodyColorSimilar: array[0..NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX-1] of Byte;
```

Answer (score -3):

like i suspected, the size of the array is the order of enum values

This change work´s;

```
    byColorSimilar: array[0..8] of Byte;            
    byUpperBodyColorSimilar: array[0..8] of Byte;   
    byLowerBodyColorSimilar: array[0..8] of Byte;
```

Comment: The arrays are `NET_COLOR_TYPE_MAX` (8) bytes in size, so the correct range is `0..7`